# automatically generate a field in javascript

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to fill in an automatically generated field where for example automatically fill in 'retired' when older then 70 is selected   in an option selection box.

could i get any help in it please :)

Comment: You've tagged Java but mentioned JavaScript in the title. Can you confirm what language you are using, and indeed what you have tried so far.

Comment: @Fatima Alnofal: Since this is your first time in SO. Little bit of advice. Always share some information like code snippet or an working example and then describe the problem. And do read SO FAQ on how to ask questions

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "generating" new field you may just conditionally change visibility of existing field. The simplest example:

```
<script>
    function checkAge(f){

      var age = f.options[f.selectedIndex].value
      var field = document.getElementById('field');

      if(age>69) 
         field.style.display='';
      else
          field.style.display='none';
    }
</script>
<select onchange="checkAge(this)">
<option value="10">10 years</option>
<option value="30">30 years</option>
.
.
.
<option value="70">70 years</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="field" value="" style="display:none" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one possible way:

```
var age = document.getElementById('age');
var status = document.getElementById('status');
age.onchange = function(){
    switch(parseInt(this.value)){
        case 20: status.value = 'working'; break;
        case 50: status.value = 'working'; break;
        case 70: status.value = 'retired'; break;
        default: status.value = 'Unknown';
    }
};
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/louisbros/zV6D8/

Answer (score 0):

Best is to show/hide the div with the field. Plus it is less resource consuming...
Otherwise try following:

```
<form id="my-form">
    <input id="age-textbox" name="age" text="" />
</form>


$('#age-textbox').blur(function(){
   if (!isNaN($(this).val())
       && parseInt($(this).val()) >= 70)
   {    
       var field = $('<input/>', { id: "test", name: "test" });
       $('#my-form').append(field);
   }
});
```